# Calling generic functions in Dart (2.0.0-dev.62.0)

Tags: dart

Why does the following code even compile (Dart VM version: **2.0.0-dev.62.0**):

```
int f<T>(T q) {
       return q.hashCode;
}       

void main() {
        print(f<int>(23));
        print(f<int>("wow"));
}
```

I thought `f<A>(..)` selects the `A` version of `f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dart VM does not use Dart 2 semantics by default when invoked directly yet (it does via Flutter, and [is coming soon for Dart v2 dev](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/AjhKsK5Mwuc)), so you need to run with `--preview-dart-2`. If you do, you'll get an error:

```
Dannys-MacBook:lib danny$ dart --preview-dart-2 test.dart
test.dart:7:22: Error: A value of type 'dart.core::String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::int'.
Try changing the type of the left hand side, or casting the right hand side to 'dart.core::int'.
        print(f<int>("wow"));
```